# how to show for every user the last two payement date and sum of mounts?

Tags: sql, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i have 2 tables where from i'm trying to extract from table 1 the last 2 taxe dates  per user who were taxed for the last time on the 19/06/2022 and with product id 12 in table 2, and the sum amount of taxes, as well as the time range between the two last taxe dates as mentionned in the image bellow .[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Comment: It's okay to help visualize the problem but you should always include sample data as text so you are not forcing people here to re-type your data from a screenshot to test their answer. Copy-and-paste from your spreadsheet and presenting as formatted text here is the least effort you should make if you expect help.

Comment: Your comment is already contradicted by the comment it is in response to.

Answer (score 0):

First step is to add a `RANK()` or `ROW_NUMBER()` to order the payments backwards, by `id` so you're only looking at the 2 last payments. Like [this](https://app.rasgoml.com/sql?transformName=rank&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Brank_columns%5D%5BargType%5D=column_list&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Brank_columns%5D%5Bcols%5D%5B0%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=tax_date&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Brank_columns%5D%5Bcols%5D%5B0%5D%5BdataType%5D=number&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Brank_columns%5D%5Bcols%5D%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=1&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bpartition_by%5D%5BargType%5D=column_list&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bpartition_by%5D%5Bcols%5D%5B0%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=id&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bpartition_by%5D%5Bcols%5D%5B0%5D%5BdataType%5D=date&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bpartition_by%5D%5Bcols%5D%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=1&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Border%5D%5BargType%5D=value&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Border%5D%5Bvalue%5D=DESC&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Brank_type%5D%5BargType%5D=value&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Brank_type%5D%5Bvalue%5D=UNIQUE&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bqualify_filter%5D%5BargType%5D=value&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bqualify_filter%5D%5Bvalue%5D=%3C%3D%202&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Balias%5D%5BargType%5D=string&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Balias%5D%5Bvalue%5D=time_ago&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Boverwrite_columns%5D%5BargType%5D=boolean&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Boverwrite_columns%5D%5Bvalue%5D=false&formState%5BtransformName%5D=rank&tableIdMap%5B9a417272-c1f9-438a-a2d1-439cda092142%5D%5Bname%5D=table1&tableIdMap%5B9a417272-c1f9-438a-a2d1-439cda092142%5D%5BcolumnIds%5D%5B0%5D=861eb324-d623-49c3-adbc-ca9103d7c125&tableIdMap%5B9a417272-c1f9-438a-a2d1-439cda092142%5D%5BcolumnIds%5D%5B1%5D=15944226-f351-49b5-ac75-59b8043cd3c8&tableIdMap%5B9a417272-c1f9-438a-a2d1-439cda092142%5D%5BcolumnIds%5D%5B2%5D=b9799e90-8925-495c-898c-dfbe0598c7a5&columnIdMap%5B861eb324-d623-49c3-adbc-ca9103d7c125%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=id&columnIdMap%5B861eb324-d623-49c3-adbc-ca9103d7c125%5D%5BdataType%5D=date&columnIdMap%5B15944226-f351-49b5-ac75-59b8043cd3c8%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=amount&columnIdMap%5B15944226-f351-49b5-ac75-59b8043cd3c8%5D%5BdataType%5D=number&columnIdMap%5Bb9799e90-8925-495c-898c-dfbe0598c7a5%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=tax_date&columnIdMap%5Bb9799e90-8925-495c-898c-dfbe0598c7a5%5D%5BdataType%5D=number&baseTableId=9a417272-c1f9-438a-a2d1-439cda092142&sqlString=SELECT%20%2A%2CRANK%28%29%20OVER%28%0A%0A%20%20%20%20PARTITION%20BY%20id%20%0A%20%20%20%20ORDER%20BY%20tax_date%20DESC%20%0A%20%20%29%20AS%20time_ago%0AFROM%20table1%0AQUALIFY%20time_ago%20%3C%3D%202).

The next step is to aggregate those to get min and max dates, and sum of amount. Like [this](https://app.rasgoml.com/sql?transformName=aggregate&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bgroup_by%5D%5BargType%5D=column_list&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bgroup_by%5D%5Bcols%5D%5B0%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=id&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bgroup_by%5D%5Bcols%5D%5B0%5D%5BdataType%5D=date&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bgroup_by%5D%5Bcols%5D%5B0%5D%5Bid%5D=1&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Baggregations%5D%5BargType%5D=agg_dict&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Baggregations%5D%5BaggDict%5D%5Btax_date%5D%5BMIN%5D=true&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Baggregations%5D%5BaggDict%5D%5Btax_date%5D%5BMAX%5D=true&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Baggregations%5D%5BaggDict%5D%5Bamount%5D%5BSUM%5D=true&formState%5BtransformName%5D=aggregate&tableIdMap%5B9a417272-c1f9-438a-a2d1-439cda092142%5D%5Bname%5D=LAST_TWO&tableIdMap%5B9a417272-c1f9-438a-a2d1-439cda092142%5D%5BcolumnIds%5D%5B0%5D=861eb324-d623-49c3-adbc-ca9103d7c125&tableIdMap%5B9a417272-c1f9-438a-a2d1-439cda092142%5D%5BcolumnIds%5D%5B1%5D=15944226-f351-49b5-ac75-59b8043cd3c8&tableIdMap%5B9a417272-c1f9-438a-a2d1-439cda092142%5D%5BcolumnIds%5D%5B2%5D=b9799e90-8925-495c-898c-dfbe0598c7a5&tableIdMap%5B9a417272-c1f9-438a-a2d1-439cda092142%5D%5BcolumnIds%5D%5B3%5D=d10162ea-5770-4313-b956-b2400ef14f90&columnIdMap%5B861eb324-d623-49c3-adbc-ca9103d7c125%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=id&columnIdMap%5B861eb324-d623-49c3-adbc-ca9103d7c125%5D%5BdataType%5D=date&columnIdMap%5B15944226-f351-49b5-ac75-59b8043cd3c8%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=amount&columnIdMap%5B15944226-f351-49b5-ac75-59b8043cd3c8%5D%5BdataType%5D=number&columnIdMap%5Bb9799e90-8925-495c-898c-dfbe0598c7a5%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=tax_date&columnIdMap%5Bb9799e90-8925-495c-898c-dfbe0598c7a5%5D%5BdataType%5D=number&columnIdMap%5Bd10162ea-5770-4313-b956-b2400ef14f90%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=time_ago&columnIdMap%5Bd10162ea-5770-4313-b956-b2400ef14f90%5D%5BdataType%5D=string&baseTableId=9a417272-c1f9-438a-a2d1-439cda092142&sqlString=WITH%20BASIC_AGGS%20AS%20%28%0ASELECT%0A%20%20%20%20id%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20MIN%28tax_date%29%20as%20tax_date_MIN%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20MAX%28tax_date%29%20as%20tax_date_MAX%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20SUM%28amount%29%20as%20amount_SUM%2C%0ACOUNT%281%29%20AS%20AGG_ROW_COUNT%0AFROM%20LAST_TWO%0AGROUP%20BY%20id%29%20%0A%0ASELECT%20BASIC_AGGS.id%2C%20BASIC_AGGS.tax_date_MIN%2C%20BASIC_AGGS.tax_date_MAX%2C%20BASIC_AGGS.amount_SUM%0AFROM%20BASIC_AGGS).

Lastly, you calculate the difference between min and max dates. Like [this](https://app.rasgoml.com/sql?transformName=datediff&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bdate_part%5D%5BargType%5D=date_part&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bdate_part%5D%5Bvalue%5D=day&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bdate_1%5D%5BargType%5D=mixed_value&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bdate_1%5D%5BvalueKey%5D=col&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bdate_1%5D%5Bcol%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=tax_date_MIN&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bdate_1%5D%5Bcol%5D%5BdataType%5D=number&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bdate_1%5D%5Bcol%5D%5Bid%5D=1&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bdate_2%5D%5BargType%5D=mixed_value&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bdate_2%5D%5BvalueKey%5D=col&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bdate_2%5D%5Bcol%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=tax_date_MAX&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bdate_2%5D%5Bcol%5D%5BdataType%5D=number&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Bdate_2%5D%5Bcol%5D%5Bid%5D=1&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Balias%5D%5BargType%5D=value&formState%5Barguments%5D%5Balias%5D%5Bvalue%5D=date_range&formState%5BtransformName%5D=datediff&tableIdMap%5B9a417272-c1f9-438a-a2d1-439cda092142%5D%5Bname%5D=AGG&tableIdMap%5B9a417272-c1f9-438a-a2d1-439cda092142%5D%5BcolumnIds%5D%5B0%5D=861eb324-d623-49c3-adbc-ca9103d7c125&tableIdMap%5B9a417272-c1f9-438a-a2d1-439cda092142%5D%5BcolumnIds%5D%5B1%5D=15944226-f351-49b5-ac75-59b8043cd3c8&tableIdMap%5B9a417272-c1f9-438a-a2d1-439cda092142%5D%5BcolumnIds%5D%5B2%5D=b9799e90-8925-495c-898c-dfbe0598c7a5&tableIdMap%5B9a417272-c1f9-438a-a2d1-439cda092142%5D%5BcolumnIds%5D%5B3%5D=d10162ea-5770-4313-b956-b2400ef14f90&columnIdMap%5B861eb324-d623-49c3-adbc-ca9103d7c125%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=id&columnIdMap%5B861eb324-d623-49c3-adbc-ca9103d7c125%5D%5BdataType%5D=date&columnIdMap%5B15944226-f351-49b5-ac75-59b8043cd3c8%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=tax_date_MIN&columnIdMap%5B15944226-f351-49b5-ac75-59b8043cd3c8%5D%5BdataType%5D=number&columnIdMap%5Bb9799e90-8925-495c-898c-dfbe0598c7a5%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=tax_date_MAX&columnIdMap%5Bb9799e90-8925-495c-898c-dfbe0598c7a5%5D%5BdataType%5D=number&columnIdMap%5Bd10162ea-5770-4313-b956-b2400ef14f90%5D%5BcolumnName%5D=amount_SUM&columnIdMap%5Bd10162ea-5770-4313-b956-b2400ef14f90%5D%5BdataType%5D=string&baseTableId=9a417272-c1f9-438a-a2d1-439cda092142&sqlString=SELECT%20%2A%2C%0A%20%20DATEDIFF%28day%2C%20tax_date_MIN%2C%20tax_date_MAX%29%20as%20DATE_RANGE%0AFROM%20AGG).

```
WITH LAST_TWO AS (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY tax_date DESC) AS time_ago
  FROM table1
  QUALIFY time_ago <= 2
),
AGG AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    MIN(tax_date) as tax_date_MIN,
    MAX(tax_date) as tax_date_MAX,
    SUM(amount) as amount_SUM
  FROM LAST_TWO
  GROUP BY id
)
SELECT id, amount_SUM, DATEDIFF(day, tax_date_MIN, tax_date_MAX) as DATE_RANGE
FROM AGG
INNER JOIN table2 ON AGG.id = table2.id
WHERE table2.product_id = 12;
```

Comment: thank you for answering but i dont see any join with the table 2 where the id should be 12.

Comment: I solved it for everyone, so you can just join and limit to a specific product at the very end.  I'll add that right now to the answer.

Comment: THANK YOU, but i think since we didnt specify and end date in 19/6 the query will return even dates after the 19/6/2022.

Comment: In the section for "LAST_TWO" you can then add a WHERE clause to filter on all records before that date, and that should work for you. That way, the "last two" is the "last two" prior to that hard coded date